# How can I align texts?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a leaderBoard. But I can't get the texts in the same alignment. How can I put the texts in the same line? As I understand it, I cannot put the texts in line because I use mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween in the row section. Is there any other way to line up the texts?

```
return Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text("Sıralama",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), ),
                                Text("İsim Soyisim",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20) ),
                                Text("Doğru cevap",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20) ),
    
                              ],
                            ),
                            Divider(thickness: 2,color: Colors.grey,),
                            Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          if (index == 0)
                                            Container(
                                                width: 50,
                                                height: 50,
                                                child: Image.asset(
                                                    "assets/images/gold.png"))
                                          else if (index == 1)
                                            Container(
                                                color: Colors.red,
                                                width: 50,
                                                height: 50,
                                                child: Image.asset(
                                                    "assets/images/silver.png"))
                                          else if (index == 2)
                                              Container(
                                                  width: 50,
                                                  height: 50,
                                                  child: Image.asset(
                                                      "assets/images/bronze.png"))
                                            else if (index > 2)
                                                Text('${index + 1}',
                                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                                          Align(
                                            child: Text(
                                                '${snapshot.data[index].name}',
                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,),
                                          Text(
                                              '${snapshot.data[index].dogruCevap.toString()}',
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ));
```

[image: This application is an image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the DataTable for better UI and easy to render the table.

[image: DataTable]

```
List<String> images = [
    "assets/images/gold.png",
    "assets/images/silver.png",
    "assets/images/bronze.png"
  ];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('DataTable'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: DataTable(
              columns: [
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Sıralama", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                DataColumn(
                    label:
                        Text("İsim Soyisim", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Doğru cevap", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
              ],
              rows: snapshot.data.asMap().entries.map<DataRow>((e) {
                return DataRow(cells: [
                  DataCell(Image.asset(images[e.key])),
                  DataCell(Text(
                      '${e.value.name}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                  DataCell(Text(
                '${e.value.dogruCevap.toString()}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))),
                ]);
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: If its help to achieve your requirement ! Please UpVote

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Table` will simplify your widget:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Score {
  final String name;
  final int score;

  Score(this.name, this.score);

  static Widget getSymbol(int position) {
    switch (position) {
      case 0:
        return Icon(Icons.directions_boat);
      case 1:
        return Icon(Icons.directions_train);
      case 2:
        return Icon(Icons.directions_bike);
      default:
        return Text((position + 1).toString(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0));
    }
  }
}

List<Score> scores = [
  Score('Azerty', 3),
  Score('Qwertyuiop', 9),
  Score('Wxcvbn', 0),
  Score('Qsd', 7),
];

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Table(
          defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
          columnWidths: {
            0: FlexColumnWidth(2),
            1: FlexColumnWidth(3),
            2: FlexColumnWidth(3),
          },
          children: [
            TableRow(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(width: 2.0)),
              ),
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text("Sıralama"),
                ),
                Text("İsim Soyisim"),
                Text("Doğru cevap"),
              ],
            ),
            ...scores
                .asMap()
                .entries
                .map(
                  (entry) => TableRow(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Score.getSymbol(entry.key),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${entry.value.name}',
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '${entry.value.score.toString()}',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```